# Firestore Regex Rule allow white space, but do not begin or end with one, and not all white spaces

Tags: regex, firebase-security, re2

I am buidling a regex2 rule for a displayed_name on Firestore. What my rule should do:

1. Allow alphanumeric, capital letters as well, the string length should be 3-16 chars
2. Allow white spaces, but it should not be all white spaces
3. Do not begin or end with a white space.

This is my current rule. It satisfies the first requirement, but I am stuck with the next 2 requirements:

```
let string_rule = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}$";
```

I have tried adding another rule such `^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$`, but it produced the errors of :

```
!  firestore.rules:29:30 - ERROR Missing a closing "
!  firestore.rules:29:30 - ERROR mismatched input 's' expecting {'&&', '.', '==', '>', '>=', '[', '<', '<=', '-', '%', '!=', '||', '+', ';', '/', '*', '?', 'in', 'is'}
!  firestore.rules:29:34 - ERROR token recognition error at: '\'
!  firestore.rules:29:38 - ERROR token recognition error at: '^'
!  firestore.rules:29:39 - ERROR token recognition error at: '\'
```

When I simply modified my rule to `"[^\s]"`, it failed with the following error:

```
firestore.rules:29:29 - ERROR Missing a closing "
!  firestore.rules:29:29 - ERROR mismatched input 's' expecting {'&&', '.', '==', '>', '>=', '[', '<', '<=', '-', '%', '!=', '||', '+', ';', '/', '*', '?', 'in', 'is'}
```

I feel like I might have gotten the rule syntax for the white space wrong. But from the documentation of RE2 I read: https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax#perl. `\s` is a Perl character class, and would allow white space, `\S` would not allow white space. What did I do wrong here, and what should my rule be to satisfy the requirments?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(?!\s)[\w ]{3,16}(?<!\s)$
```

This uses negative look ahead/behind to assert the first and last are not whitespace.

`[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is the same as `\w`.

You don't need to check for "not all whitespace", because if the first and last are not whitespace, the whole input is not all whitespace.